# why the delay option doesn't work in mouse.move method when I use it in pyppeteer for skip identify

Tags: python, puppeteer

I write a test code to skip identify which is a slider block. and I use the pyppeteer module. but when I try to hover the slider block and move mouse, I found that the move speed can't control though I use delay option in move method. it seems doesn't work.

my code like this:

```
@tries(retry_if_result_none)
async def mouse_slide(box=None, page=None):
    try:
        await page.hover('#nc_1_n1z')    #move to slider button
        await page.mouse.down()             # press tee mouse
        await page.mouse.move(box['x']+box['width'], box['y'], {'delay': random.randint(1000, 2000)})   # move mouse to speial location
        await page.mouse.up()                 # release mouse
    except Exception as e:
        print(e, '***********************************:slide login False')
        slider_move_text = await page.Jeval('.errloading .nc-lang-cnt', 'node => node.textContent');
        if "哎呀，出错了，点击" in slider_move_text:
            refresh_btn = await page.querySelector('.errloading .nc-lang-cnt a');
            await page.evaluate('(element) => element.click()', refresh_btn);
            await asyncio.sleep(3);
            slider = await page.querySelector('#nocaptcha');
            box = await slider.boundingBox();
        return None
    else:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        slider_again = await page.Jeval('.nc-lang-cnt', 'node => node.textContent')
        if slider_again != '验证通过':
            return None
        else:
            await page.screenshot({'path': './headless-slide-result.png'})
            return 1
```

The code {'delay': random.randint(1000, 2000)} isn't work, the mouse move so fast. is any where that I used have problem?

Answer (score 1):

[mouse.move](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#mousemovex-y-options) doesn't have an option for delay.

You can try to move and sleep in a loop like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    await page.mouse.move(i * 10, i * 10);
    await page.waitFor(100);
   }
```